# Survey data Cleaning - Grouping Age range - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, survey

I have this data set with the following values counts for the column `Age`:

```
>>> game['Age'].value_counts()

Between 18 -25     131
Between 26 - 30     21
Under 18            10
31 or more           7
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

I´m trying **to create a regrouping of values with 2 groups for this column 'Age'** :

```
 - <=25 // (grouping Between 18 -25 + Under 18 )
 - >=26 // (grouping Between 26 - 30 + 31 or more )
```

I have been trying to play groupby function but no good result yet.
Can you please help?

Comment: what does grouping mean? Do you want to sum the values from `<= 25` and `>=26` or do something more complex?

Comment: Hi @rafaelc, basically I would like to create 2 new values , one that regroup all the people that responded 'Between 18 -25' + 'Under 18' and another value that regroup 'Between 26 - 30 ' + '31 or more' answers.

Comment: Since this is a very small series, can't you do this manually? `s = game['Age'].value_counts()` , then `pd.DataFrame({'age': [s['Between 18 - 25'] + s['Under 18'], s['Between 26 -30'] + s['31 or more']])` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select`:

```
mapping = {
    'Between 18 -25': '<=25',
    'Under 18': '<=25',
    'Between 26 - 30': '>=26',
    '31 or more': '>=26',
}

df['Age'] = np.select([df['Age'] == k for k in mapping.keys()], mapping.values())
```

Or just use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Age'] == 'Between 18 -25', 'Age'] = '<=25'
df.loc[df['Age'] == 'Under 18', 'Age'] = '<=25'
df.loc[df['Age'] == 'Between 26 - 30', 'Age'] = '>=26'
df.loc[df['Age'] == '31 or more', 'Age'] = '>=26'
```

Or `isin`:

```
df.loc[df['Age'].isin(['Between 18 -25', 'Under 18']), 'Age'] = '<=25'
df.loc[df['Age'].isin(['Between 26 - 30', '31 or more']), 'Age'] = '>=26'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explain the problem in a better way or share your code for better understanding.

This can be acheived by using `np.where()` method

```
import numpy as np

game["How old are you?"] = np.where(((game["How old are you?"]=="Between 18 -25") |
                                     (game["How old are you?"]=="Under 18")), "Under 25", "26 or more")


game["How old are you?"].value_counts()
```

You should see an output something like this

```
Under 25    ...
26 or more  ...
```

Comment: found a solution doing like that: 

'game2['Age2'] = 0

for i in range(len(game2["Age"])):
    if (game2["Age"].iloc[i] == "Between 18 -25") | (game2["Age"].iloc[i] == "Under 18"):
        game2["Age2"].iloc[i] = "<=25"
    else: 
        game2["Age2"].iloc[i] = ">25"'

Answer (score 0):

found the solution doing this one, thanks for your help!

```
game2['Age2'] = 0

for i in range(len(game2["Age"])):
if (game2["Age"].iloc[i] == "Between 18 -25") | (game2["Age"].iloc[i] == "Under 18"):
    game2["Age2"].iloc[i] = "<=25"
else: 
    game2["Age2"].iloc[i] = ">25"
```